# Groupby streak of numbers and a mask to groupby two rows after each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [20, 1, 55, 333, 444, 1, 2, 10], 'b': [20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22]})
```

I want to group them by column `b` and two rows after each group.
This is the output that I need:

```
    a   b
0  20   20
1   1   20
2   55  21
3  333  21

     a   b
2   55  21
3  333  21
4  444  21
5   1   22
6   2   22

    a   b
5   1   22
6   2   22
7  10   22
```

I know that I need a mask. I have tried some of them but didn't work. This is one of my tries:

```
df.groupby(df.b.diff().cumsum().eq(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this just with a grouper as groups cannot overlap.

You can however use a groupby with side effects by referencing the original DataFrame:

```
(df.groupby('b')
   .apply(lambda g: df.loc[g.index[0]:g.index[-1]+2])
)
```

Output:

```
        a   b
b            
20 0   20  20
   1    1  20
   2   55  21
   3  333  21
21 2   55  21
   3  333  21
   4  444  21
   5    1  22
   6    2  22
22 5    1  22
   6    2  22
   7   10  22
```

##### As a loop:

```
for k, g in df.groupby('b'):
    print(k)
    print(df.loc[g.index[0]:g.index[-1]+2])
```

Output:

```
20
     a   b
0   20  20
1    1  20
2   55  21
3  333  21
21
     a   b
2   55  21
3  333  21
4  444  21
5    1  22
6    2  22
22
    a   b
5   1  22
6   2  22
7  10  22
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this affect performance?

Comment: Compare to what? ;)

Comment: normal groupby :) I mean without using index.

Comment: The `groupby` is likely the limiting step. So I would say, no effect.