# groupby streak of numbers and one row after it

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})
```

And my desired outcome which is about grouping them is:

```
    a
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   0

4   1
5   0

6   1
7   1
8   0

10  1
11  1
12  0
```

Basically, I want to group them by streak of 1 and one row after where streak ends.

For example for the first group I want the first three rows plus the row after it.

I have tried the solutions of these posts: [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141642/groupby-streak-of-numbers-and-a-mask-to-groupby-two-rows-after-each-group), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046286/groupby-two-columns-in-pandas).

And also this code:

```
df.groupby(df.a.diff().cumsum().eq(1))
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reverse [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to form the groups:

```
g = df.loc[::-1, 'a'].eq(0).cumsum()

out = [g for _,g in df.groupby(g, sort=False) if len(g)>1]
```

Output:

```
[   a
 0  1
 1  1
 2  1
 3  0,
    a
 4  1
 5  0,
    a
 6  1
 7  1
 8  0,
     a
 10  1
 11  1
 12  0]
```

Comment: Note that if you don't have only 0/1 you can replace `.eq(0)` by `.ne(1)`, also this code assumes at least 2 rows in the input DataFrame