# groupby streak of numbers and one row after it then check the first value of a column for each group

Tags: python, pandas

This is an extension to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77372530/groupby-streak-of-numbers-and-one-row-after-it).

This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [ 1, 1, 1,  0, 1,  0,  1, 1,  0,  0, 1, 1,  0,  0],
        'b': [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
    }
)
```

And my desired outcome which is about grouping them is:

```
    a  b
4   1  1
5   0 -1

10  1  1
11  1  1
12  0 -1
```

Basically, I want to group them by streak of 1 and one row after where streak ends in column `a`.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77372543/10200497) does that:

```
g = df.loc[::-1, 'a'].eq(0).cumsum()

out = [g for _,g in df.groupby(g, sort=False) if len(g)>1]
```

But now what I want is check if the first value in `b` for each group is 1.

I don't know what is the best approach to check the first value of `b`.
This is what I have tried but I am not sure if it works in every case.

```
groups = df.groupby(g).filter(lambda x: x.b.iloc[0] == 1)
```

I have experienced some situations where the code works in an example but it does not work in every situation with different conditions so I want to double check my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
g = df['a'].eq(0).cumsum().sub(df['a'].eq(0)) # grouper
cond1 = df.groupby(g)['b'].transform('first').eq(1) # first of colb is 1
cond2 = df.groupby(g)['b'].transform('count').gt(1) # len of group  is greater than 1
out = [d for _, d in df[cond1 & cond2].groupby(g)] # filter by cond1 and cond2
```

out

```
[   a  b
 4  1  1
 5  0 -1,
     a  b
 10  1  1
 11  1  1
 12  0 -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using `.ffill` with `limit=`:

```py
mask = (df["a"] != df["a"].shift()).cumsum()
mask[df["a"] != 1] = np.nan
mask = mask.ffill(limit=1)

for _, g in df.groupby(mask):
    if g["b"].iat[0] != 1:
        continue
    print(g)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
   a  b
4  1  1
5  0 -1

    a  b
10  1  1
11  1  1
12  0 -1
```