# groupby streak of numbers and one row after it then check the first value of a column for each group and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        'b': [1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]    
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want. I want to create column `c`:

```
   a  b  c
0   0  1  0
1   0 -1  0
2   1 -1  0
3   1 -1  0
4   1  1  1
5   1 -1  1
6   0  1  0
7   0  1  0
8   0 -1  0
9   1  1  1
10  1  1  1
11  1 -1  1
12  0  1  0
13  0  1  0
14  1 -1  0
15  1 -1  1
16  0  1  0
```

This is basically an extension to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77372530/groupby-streak-of-numbers-and-one-row-after-it). The highlighted rows below summarize the way that this needs to be done.

[image]

First of all in column `a`, groups are created by streak of 1s and one row after the streak ends. The highlighted rows in column `a` are these groups. The solution for this step is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77372543/10200497).

Now what I need is to check column `b` for each group in `a`. Find the first value that is 1 in `b` for each group. And then any value that comes before this becomes 0. This is how column `c` is created.

For example for first group in `a`, the first value that column `b` is 1 is row number `4`. The previous values in that group becomes 0. And the result is the first highlighted group in column `c`.

Note that if for a group, all the values in `b` are NOT 1, the corresponding group in `c` will become all 0s.

This is what I have tried but I can't find the complete solution:

```
g = df.loc[::-1, 'a'].eq(0).cumsum()
x = df.groupby(g).filter(lambda x: x.b.iloc[0] == 1)
```

Comment: The condition to create `c` is not entirely clear (but I'm happy to edit),  if you only want 0/1 then why is the second to last value in `c` a 1?

Comment: @mozway My bad. I edited the dataframe and uploaded the corresponding image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation of the linked answer using [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) on `df['b'].eq(1)` and an intermediate mask derived from the grouper:

```
m = df.loc[::-1, 'a'].eq(0)
g = m.cumsum()

df['c'] = np.where(df['b'].eq(1).groupby(g).cummax() & ~m, 1, 0)
```

Output and intermediates:

```
    a  b  c      m     ~m  cummax  cummax&~m
0   0  1  0   True  False    True      False
1   0 -1  0   True  False   False      False
2   1 -1  0  False   True   False      False
3   1 -1  0  False   True   False      False
4   1  1  1  False   True    True       True
5   1 -1  1  False   True    True       True
6   0  1  0   True  False    True      False
7   0  1  0   True  False    True      False
8   0 -1  0   True  False   False      False
9   1  1  1  False   True    True       True
10  1  1  1  False   True    True       True
11  1 -1  1  False   True    True       True
12  0  1  0   True  False    True      False
13  0  1  0   True  False    True      False
14  1 -1  0  False   True   False      False
15  1  1  1  False   True    True       True
16  0  1  0   True  False    True      False
```

Comment: m is not defined!

Comment: @x_Amir_x oops wrong copy paste

Answer (score 1):

Create mask by [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) and chain with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), for set `0,1` cast boolean to integers:

```
g = df.loc[::-1, 'a'].eq(0).cumsum()
df['c'] = (df['b'].eq(1).groupby(g).cummax() & g.duplicated()).astype(int)
print (df)
    a  b  c
0   0  1  0
1   0 -1  0
2   1 -1  0
3   1 -1  0
4   1  1  1
5   1 -1  1
6   0  1  0
7   0  1  0
8   0 -1  0
9   1  1  1
10  1  1  1
11  1 -1  1
12  0  1  0
13  0  1  0
14  1 -1  0
15  1  1  1
16  0  1  0
```